# Switching focus in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, focus, xdotool

Please help me understand the source of a little issue I have when **trying to make a window lose focus** in a Bash script invoked with a hotkey combination in Openbox on Linux.

I have a couple of lines in the script:

```
wmctrl -F -r "${TERMINAL_TITLE}" -b add,shaded,below
xdotool key alt+Tab
```

The first line shades the window in question and "drops" it below all the other but it remains focused. The second line should in theory move focus to the next window in the stack…

…and it does! But only if the script in run with gmrun, or in the terminal itself (because the window i'm trying to hide and defocus is a terminal emulator).

However it doesn't work as intended if the script is invoked with an Openbox hotkey (which is what I need), or run in a neighbor terminal (just for a test).

I'm not a proficient bash user by any means. I can usually knock together a simple script here and there for my humble needs but here I'm just lost. Will appreciate advice.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this was probably a case of an XY question, at least to some degree. there's currently no way to control focus with wmctrl. however if i stop trying to do that, and instead of shading the window just minimize it – i actually achieve what i need to do. although this too can't be done with wmctrl, had to use xdotool:

```
xdotool windowminimize $( xdotool search --name "${TERMINAL_TITLE}" )
```

focus switches. done!